# Sails.js is not working with forever

Tags: node.js, sails.js, forever

I m new on both sails.js and node.js. 
I created a simple api with sails.js. It works fine when I start it with `sails lift --prod`. On the other hand when I start the application with `forever start app.js --prod` and it always returns 0 altough I dont not get any error and warning and I can see my app.js in the list with the forever list command.
I created a simple node.js application to test forever and it worked as expected. 
I tried to run my Sails.js application both my local windows and linux/ubuntu machine on digital ocean, they worked fine with sails lift but not forever. Also I tried `node app.js --verbose` and it was ok.  My sails version is 0.11.4. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well eventually I start my application with forever. Those are what I did

1. I checked forever commands and saw logs command which provides running forever applications log files.
2. When I checked the log file under c:\users\user-name\forever I saw a warning about Sails migrate settings should have been done.
3. Then I read  [this documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html) about Sails migrate settings and I set my project as migrte: 'safe' .

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is similar to this: [Cannot run with forever js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2133)

I think, you should open `config/models.js` and add `migrate: 'safe'`.

Comment: Your answer is exacty what I did shortly, just I would like to give more details so that if someone has similar issue, they can follow up the path . Thank you.